# Create RasterSymbolizer SLD style in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm trying to create a sld style for my raster, but I'm getting this error :

```
line 18: cvc-complex-type.2.1 : L'élément 'sld:Normalize' ne doit comporter aucun enfant ([children]) de type caractère ou élément d'information, car le type de contenu du type est vide.
line 28: cvc-complex-type.2.1 : L'élément 'sld:Normalize' ne doit comporter aucun enfant ([children]) de type caractère ou élément d'information, car le type de contenu du type est vide.
line 38: cvc-complex-type.2.1 : L'élément 'sld:Normalize' ne doit comporter aucun enfant ([children]) de type caractère ou élément d'information, car le type de contenu du type est vide.
```

This is the sld file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld">
    <sld:UserLayer>
        <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
            <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
        </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>ahfir</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title/>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name/>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
                      <sld:ChannelSelection>
                        <sld:RedChannel>
                        <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
                        <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                          <sld:Normalize>
                           <sld:VendorOption name='algorithm'>StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name='minValue'>-55.2689</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name='maxValue'>214.7722</sld:VendorOption>
                          </sld:Normalize>
                        </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                        </sld:RedChannel>
                        <sld:GreenChannel>
                        <sld:SourceChannelName>2</sld:SourceChannelName>
                        <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                          <sld:Normalize>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">-41.9121</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">163.9293</sld:VendorOption>
                          </sld:Normalize>
                        </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                        </sld:GreenChannel>
                        <sld:BlueChannel>
                        <sld:SourceChannelName>3</sld:SourceChannelName>
                        <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                          <sld:Normalize>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">-22.1867</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">77.2479</sld:VendorOption>
                          </sld:Normalize>
                        </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                        </sld:BlueChannel>
                      </sld:ChannelSelection>
                    </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:UserLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I followed exactly the Geoserver's documentation, here is the [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html)

I'm using Geoserver 2.15.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sld schema that geoserver is using to verify the sld has not been updated to recognise the vendor options in side the normalise tag. The sld will work fine if you apply it.

Comment: Thank you it worked !